# chat web service with multiple processes listening on same port

Tags: node.js, networking, process, load-balancing

I am making a chat-application. To scale and use all cores, i am creating multiple servers which are listening on same port given by infrastructure for listening. Every information is `in memory`.

However, is it possible that lets say.. `A and B` are chatting each other and have information in `process1` and `X and Y` are chatting and have information in `process2`.

My question is :

1. Do programs compete for each message ? If a new message comes from `A`, Can it go to `process2` which have no information about `A` or `B`.

Or does it depend upon something like if i use simple `http` messages above problem would happen but if i use `web-sockets` it would not happen.

I am using `node.js`, though i consider it to be a language independent problem.

so, code is like :

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  http.Server(function(req, res) { ... }).listen(8000);
}
```

Should i make only one `listening-process` which would act like `intelligent load-balancer` that would send the message to right process ?

Comment: @downvoter any comments/reasons for down-voting this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, processes compete for each message. So, to solve this problem :

I can have the data like session or chatter-info out of the web-servers in like a shared-database like `Redis` or `memcache` and query it from each web-server.

I can also store the web-socket connections in `mongodb` too. so, it just becomes easier to scale.